# Is there any webcam finger tracking software available?

Tags: software-recommendation, mouse, webcam

I have been looking all over the place for finger tracking software for my webcam that I have built in to my laptop (for example, when you move your finger around and your mouse follows your finger where ever it goes)

Thanks for the help if you can find something like that.

Comment: so there is not anything for ubuntu for a tracking software thing?

Answer (score 5):

The project is called Community Core Vision:
http://ccv.nuigroup.com/
[image: CCV]

Also there is a project called [TUIO](http://www.tuio.org/): [image: tuio]

Comment: Community Core Vision doesn't appear to be installing https://github.com/nuigroup/ccv2/issues/26